# zip generators passing parameters from a list of tuples

Tags: python, iterator, tuples

I have a function:

```
def func(i, k):
  j = 0
  while True:
    yield j * i + k
    j += 1
```

And some `i` and `k` instances:

```
pars = [(2, 4), (1, 5), (7, 2)]
```

How can I zip over func of pars without knowing the length of pars? Like this:

```
for func_tups in zip(func(2, 4), func(1, 5), func(7, 2)):
   print func_tups
```

I imagine some combination of map, zip, lambda, `*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for [`itertools.starmap()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap):

```
from itertools import starmap

for func_tups in zip(*starmap(func, pairs)):
    # warning, infinite loop unless you have a break condition
```

Here `starmap()` applies an arbitrary length `pairs` as arguments to `func`, which you can then pass to `zip()` as separate arguments. You can't use `map()` here, as it only supports callables with *one* argument.

This presumes you are using Python 3 `zip()`; on Python 2 you'd obviously need to use `itertools.izip()` to handle the infinite sequence of tuples produced by the `func()` generators as an iterable:

```
from itertools import starmap, izip

for func_tups in izip(*starmap(func, pairs)):
    # warning, infinite loop unless you have a break condition
```

Comment: @Eric: Yes, I forgot the `zip()` part at first.

Comment: It gets stuck in the while loop despite the yield, am I missing something?

Comment: @perreal: On python 2, yes. Use `itertools.izip()` there.

Answer (score 7):

```
for func_tup in zip(*(func(*p) for p in pairs)):
    print func_tup
```

Although this probably reads better as two lines:

```
iterators = (func(*pair) for pair in pairs)  # aka starmap
for func_tup in zip(*iterators):
    print func_tup
```